# My app returns 403 error although config seems to work properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I created jwt security config in my spring-boot app and always when I have token in `Authorization` header added my app returns `403`. I created this config basen on this [app](https://github.com/ali-bouali/spring-boot-3-jwt-security).

Here's my SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
  private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/v1/auth/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final JwtService jwtService;
  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
      @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
      @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
  ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    final String jwt;
    final String userEmail;
    if (authHeader == null ||!authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }
    jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
    userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
    if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
      UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
      if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails,
            null,
            userDetails.getAuthorities()
        );
        authToken.setDetails(
            new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
      }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

ApplicationConfig

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

  private final UserRepository repository;

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return username -> repository.findByEmail(username)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
    return config.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

}
```

JwtService

```
@Service
public class JwtService {

  private static final String SECRET_KEY = "secretkeyhere";

  public String extractUsername(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
  }

  public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
    final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
  }

  public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
    return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
  }

  public String generateToken(
      Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
      UserDetails userDetails
  ) {
    return Jwts
        .builder()
        .setClaims(extraClaims)
        .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
        .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
        .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
        .compact();
  }

  public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = extractUsername(token);
    return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
  }

  private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
  }

  private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
  }

  private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts
        .parserBuilder()
        .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
        .build()
        .parseClaimsJws(token)
        .getBody();
  }

  private Key getSignInKey() {
    byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
  }
}
```

To test it I send `GET` request to `http://localhost:8080/v1/example` in postman with `Bearer token...` in `Authorization` header. Response was 403 Forbidden.

Here's controller class.

ExampleController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/example")
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping
    public String getTestMessage() {
        return "test message";
    }
}
```

I tried changing configuration, checking authentication, test all methods, but everything seems to work properly

Comment: What Spring Boot version?

Comment: 3.0.1, same as in the project on which I was based

Comment: There are a lot of things going on in this code and it makes it difficult to pinpoint the problem. For example, we don't know **(1)** how you're retrieving your JWT token, **(2)** whether you're correctly sending your JWT token in your request **(3)** nor if you're sending a valid JWT token. This is because your question doesn't contain a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suggest that you debug your `JwtAuthenticationFilter`to pinpoint the issue or provide the necessary information so we can try it ourselves.

Comment: For example, you'll get a 403 if your `JwtAuthenticationFilter` doesn't set an `Authentication` object. This could happen because **(1)** `authHeader` is `null` or **(2)** doesn't start with `Bearer`or **(3)** because `userEmail` is `null` or **(4)** if your `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` somehow already includes an authentication object or **(5)** if your token isn't valid.

Comment: sure, I understand. i've checked it - I added sout after `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);` in JwtAuthenticationFilter and Authentication was properly set. it seans that any of this options happens